# How to pick id of images dynamically on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hy!
I am calling images from database in a div. By clicking on any image, i am displaying a same modal having product details.

For displaying modal, in JavaScript, i am receiving the images by src, that was clicked and hence opening same modal.
Now i want to get the id of each image that is clicked for using that id in php script.
How can i do that?

php

```
<div  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>

<h3 align='center'>$product_name</h3>
<center>
<img src='admin_area/product_images/u_buyer_product_img/$product_image1' class='getSrc' /> 
<br></center>
</div>
```

javascript

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.getSrc').click(function() {
        var src =$(this).attr('src');

        $('.showPic').attr('src') = src;
     });

});
</script>
```

html

```
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
      <img src="" class="showPic">
        <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

<h3 align="left">Product Name 
 </h3>
  <p>Product Discription</p>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
            <div>
              <label> Product-Code :- </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label> Quantity :- </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label> Price :- </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label> Action :- </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Just use `this.id`

Comment: `$(this).attr('id');` ?

Comment: I can't see any id attribute  here in html?

Comment: @guradio
How i can check this now against each image?

Comment: on your click event you can use the `$(this).attr('id')` to get the id of the clicked image

Comment: @guradio
Hello excuse me !
Where is id coming from?
I never used it anywhere???

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide : Would you elaborate more... What do you need and when... I am a bit confused with your question ..

Comment: I have solved it myself.
Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that in the PHP script you have and `$id` variable containing the ID of the image being displayed:

```
<div  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>
  <h3 align='center'>$product_name</h3>
  <center>
    <img src='admin_area/product_images/u_buyer_product_img/$product_image1' class='getSrc' data-image-id='$id' /> 
    <br>
  </center>
</div>
```

Then in JS you can retrieve the id:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.getSrc').click(function() {
        var src =$(this).attr('src');
        var id = $(this).data('image-id');
        $('.showPic').attr('src') = src;
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have already implemented this.
By the way, thanks for your time and interest!